# Parsing yaml in perl --> Code: YAML_LOAD_ERR_BAD_MAP_ELEMENT

Tags: perl, parsing, yaml

I have a yaml file which is generated from another source as shown below.

```
connect1:
   connect2:
     - { level1 : name, level2: age,                                                        
         level3: gender}
```

My code looks something like this --?

```
use YAML::Tiny qw(LoadFile);
use YAML;
use YAML::Loader;
use YAML::Syck;
use YAML qw(LoadFile);
use Data::Dumper;

   my $data = LoadFile("file.yaml");
   my @config = $data->{connect1}->{connect2};
   print Dumper(@config);
```

I'm getting this following error -->
YAML Error: Invalid element in map
   Code: YAML_LOAD_ERR_BAD_MAP_ELEMENT
   Line: 3
   Document: 1

If level1 , level2 and leve3 are in the same line then I dont see this issue. 
I see the issue because of indentation I think. 
But there is no way that I can change this file.yaml. 
So is there a way in perl that I can still parse this yaml file without modifying the file.yaml?

Comment: [YAML::XS](http://p3rl.org/YAML::XS) loads the file without problems, as does [YAML::PP](http://p3rl.org/YAML::PP).

Comment: It's a bit confusing because you load several YAML modules. Effectively you are using `YAML.pm`'s `LoadFile`. `YAML.pm` does not support any kind of flow style on multiple lines, that includes plain and quoted strings, and flow style collections `{ ... }`, `[ ... ]`. It probably never will

Answer (score 7):

The state of YAML in Perl is a bit unfortunate, because there are several modules which support different features.

YAML::Syck, YAML::XS and YAML::PP can parse your example. YAML::XS is probably a good choice right now.

[YAML.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML) was the first perl module for YAML, and it was written for YAML 1.0.

[YAML::Syck](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML::Syck) is based on libsyck, which was written for YAML 1.0. It can parse more than YAML.pm though.

[YAML::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML::XS) is based on libyaml, written for YAML 1.1. You should be able to parse most YAML with it, and libyaml is used in (or was ported to) many other languages.

[YAML::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML::Tiny) just supports a subset of YAML, which does not include flow collections `{ ... }`, `[ ... ]` and aliases/anchors (`&x`, `*x`)

[YAML::PP](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML::PP) is pretty new and already can parse a lot, but it's also not complete yet. It aims to parse YAML 1.2 (and it will also partially support 1.1 in the future) Disclaimer: I'm the author

Here you can find my slides from the London Perl Workshop 2017:
https://perlpunk.github.io/slides.lpw2017/yaml-where-and-how-to-use/

Starting at slide 24 you'll find a quick overview over the 5 modules.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [cpan page](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML::Tiny)

```
In exchange for this adding this extreme flexibility, it provides support 
for only a limited subset of YAML. But the subset supported contains most 
of the features for the more common uses of YAML.
```

So I think you might need to try a more complete YAML parser

If you didn't fancy that then you could investigate a command line utility to do the parsing, such as [`yq`](https://yq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or another YAML to JSON conversion and process as JSON.